# LEFT JOIN (SELECT) Syntax Error In From Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can some one point out to me the error in this sql statement?

```
SELECT CommTypes.Description, Intro.[Percent]
FROM CommTypes
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM IntroducerBasis 
    WHERE IntroducerBasis.IntroducerCode='AG' 
       AND IntroducerBasis.BasisNumber=1
) AS Intro
ON CommTypes.ID = Intro.CommTypeID;
```

The error highlights the subsequent SELECT statement as the source of the error.

The Error is "Syntax Error In From Clause"

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Syntax Error In From Clause

Comment: Paste the whole error msgh

Comment: what kind of sql server are you using?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. I've copy pasted your query, replaced tables and fields with random ones from my database, and the query executes successfully.

Comment: do you have the column `CommTypeID` in the results of your subquery?

Comment: @MaveRick Yes CommTypeID exists

Comment: please add the error you are getting letterly so we can check

Comment: @robprestwood as a test can you give first table an alias as well `FROM CommTypes AS T1 ` and use it in the join `ON T1.ID = Intro.CommTypeID` ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you are only returning a value from the parent table, why do you need the subquery at all?

However, try specifying columns rather than `*` in the subquery:

```
SELECT CommTypes.Description
FROM CommTypes
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
    field1,
    field2
    FROM IntroducerBasis 
    WHERE IntroducerCode='AG' AND BasisNumber=1) AS Intro
ON CommTypes.ID = Intro.CommTypeID;
```

Comment: This doesn't affect the results. Intro.Percent should also be a part of the initial select, I have amended the original to reflect this

Comment: @D Stanley Syntax Error In From Clause, the 2nd SELECT statement is highlighted

Comment: Yes, the 2nd select statement executes as expected in isolation

Comment: I've recreated the tables (using the fields that you provide) and the query executes just fine.  You may need to post the _whole_ query to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that type of join to a select statement is allowed in MS-ACCESS.
Try this instead:

```
SELECT CommTypes.Description, IntroducerBasis.Percent
FROM CommTypes
LEFT JOIN IntroducerBasis 
   ON CommTypes.ID = IntroducerBasis.CommTypeID
   AND IntroducerBasis.IntroducerCode='AG' 
   AND IntroducerBasis.BasisNumber=1;
```

Comment: This negates the left join, only giving values for CommTypes.ID where a corresponding IntroducerBasis.CommTypeID exists

Comment: Right, sorry about that. It should all be included in the join. I've edited as such.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CommTypes.[Description], Intro.[Percent]
FROM CommTypes
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM IntroducerBasis 
    WHERE IntroducerBasis.IntroducerCode='AG' 
       AND IntroducerBasis.BasisNumber=1
) AS Intro
ON CommTypes.ID = Intro.CommTypeID
```

`Percent` is a reserved keyword, if your fields must be named the same as some keywords, simply wrap them in square brackets so that they can be distinguised.

Comment: This isn't the issue, updated op to prevent further confusion

Comment: @robprestwood You might want to wrap Description also

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an Access Limitation as creating the sub query in access and joining to that works perfectly.